# Merging cells with Ruby Gem Spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, spreadsheet

How do I merge cells using the Ruby Spreadsheet gem.  I would like to merge the first 6 cells on the first row of a worksheet.  When I try the following it does not work:

```
merge_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :align => :merge
6.times do |j|
  sheet.row(0).set_format(j,merge_format)
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply do

```
sheet.merge_cells(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)
```

If you want to go with `set_format`, I'd advise trying `:vertical_align => :merge`, although I didn't use it since `merge_cells` always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, where did you find that method?  I could not find it on http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

Comment: I was browsing sources actually looking for the same answer :) The fact that it's undocumented might leave a chance that they change or remove the API, but I still found it convenient to use.

Comment: Thanks!  It's been like two years and it's still not in the docs... (sigh)